# How to zoom out in WebView on Android TV [SDK 22]?

Tags: android, webview, android-tv

I am having problems in zooming out the content of a WebView which is too large for the default scale.

I am developing for a 720p Android TV and I followed all the possible suggestions out there:

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.main_wv);
    webView.setInitialScale(1);
    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);
    webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

This is my current setup, I tried enabling some of them and not others but still no change.

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/main_wv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></WebView>
</android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Am I making any mistake or is it some sort of wicked bug?

I just want to zoom out as far as possible to be able to fit a huge graph which wouldn't be completely shown otherwise.

**EDIT1**: I tried changing `android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat` to `FrameLayout`. Nothing changed.

**EDIT2**: I also tried `webView.zoomBy(0.02f)`, still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a Try with Adding this to `WebView.`

```
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

Try with `Frame Layout` in your `XML`.

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            />

    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I suggest you to take `Frame Layout` in your xml and `Web View` inside it give a try.

Comment: I am not sure May be this will be wicked bug for `Android TV`.